# Почему система не доверяет самоподписанному сертификату, хотя он в списке доверенных?

Tags: linux, apache, google-chrome, ssl, openssl

Я работаю с apache (apache2.4.38) и мне, как не странно, понадобилось сделать https версию сайта. Но результат такой: [image: Результат]
Вот, что делал:

Создаю пару ключей с помощью команды

```
sudo -u www-data openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /var/www/html/cert/key.key -out /var/www/html/cert/key.crt
```

С правами root открываю в редакторе `/etc/apache2/sites-available/localhost.conf` и приписываю:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ... # Те же настройки, что и для без шифрования
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/cert/key.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/cert/key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Добавляю сертификат в доверенные:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo cp /var/www/html/cert/key.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Перезагружаю apache и пробую зайти.

В чём проблема?

Comment: Если ничего не путаю, в список доверенных должны добавляться не просто сертификаты, а центры сертификации, которые в свою очередь подписывают другие сертификаты. Так что самоподписанные в пролёте

Comment: нет. система не доверяет ( тут конкретно гуглхром ) потому что у тебя неправильный сертификат. у тебя должно быть поле SAN, если выпустишь поле сан с ip-адресом 127.0.0.1 и адресом  localhost.somedomain и его добавишь в хостст, хоть на винде хоть на линуксе доверять будет. для упрощения понимания возьми какуюнить утилитку типа XCA в ней удобней генерировать чем через опенссл. смысл в том что браузер не просто требует сертификат, а втом, что у тебя еще должны быть в нем прописаны FQDN которые этот сертификат удостоверяет. А вот IE достаточно чтобы A-запись совпадала с CN. Хрому - НЕТ.

Comment: Добавьте вывод команды ` openssl x509 -noout -text -in /var/www/html/cert/key.crt`. Именно, что у вас написано в поле subject? Вторая мысль. Хром в линуксе не использует системное хранилище сертификатов. Нужно добавлять ручками: https://superuser.com/questions/104146/add-permanent-ssl-certificate-exception-in-chrome-linux